# Images from Camera2Api in Nexus 5 appear blurry

Tags: android, android-camera2

This is my first attempt at accessing and clicking images using the Camera2Api.
I'm using the Nexus 5 running on API 23.
Though I can get the camera preview, but I cannot understand why does the frame gets locked after the capture request and also the images generated are blurry/totaly unclear.
I've been stuck with this issue for a while now. Any advise would be appreciated
Attached is my MainActivity Code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
        static {
         ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0,90);
         ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90,0);
         ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180,270);
         ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270,180);
         }
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final int STATE_PREVIEW=0;
private static final int STATE_WAIT_AF_LOCK=1;
private static final int STATE_PICTURE_CAPTURED=2;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST = 2;

private int mState;
private static LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread; 
private final Handler mUIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
   @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
       swapImageAdapter();
   }
};
private static File mImageFile;

private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
private TextureView mTextureView;
private Button mCaptureButton;
private File mImageFolder;
private static String mImageFileName;
private Size mPreviewSize; //mImageSize
private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
private String mCameraId;
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private CaptureRequest mPreviewCaptureRequest;
private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder;
private CameraCaptureSession mCameraCaptureSession;
private ImageReader mImageReader; 
private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener =
        new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener(){
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader){
                Log.i(TAG,"OnImageAvailableListener!!!");

                mBackgroundHandler.post(new 
  ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(),mUIHandler));
            }
        };
private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable{

    private final Image mImage;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    ImageSaver(Image image){
        Log.i(TAG,"imgSaver const");
        mImage=image;

        mHandler=null;
    }
    ImageSaver(Image image,Handler handler){
        Log.i(TAG,"imgSaver const");

        mImage =image;
        mHandler =handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        Log.i(TAG,"In ImageSaver run()");

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer=mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byteBuffer.rewind();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.capacity()];

        byteBuffer.get(bytes);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

        try{
            fileOutputStream =new FileOutputStream(mImageFileName);
            fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            Log.i(TAG,"Closing Image!!");
            mImage.close();
            if(fileOutputStream!=null){
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        Log.i(TAG,"sending Message from Image Saver run()");
        message.sendToTarget();
    }

}
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mSessionCaptureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureStarted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
        super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
        Log.i(TAG,"mSessionCaptureCallback+ onCaptureStarted");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result){
        super.onCaptureCompleted(session,request,result);
        Log.i(TAG,"mSessionCaptureCallback+ onCaptureCompleted");
        process(result); //process the result once capture session request is completed.
        Log.i(TAG,"mSessionCaptureCallback+ onCaptureCompleted ENDS!");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCaptureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, CaptureFailure failure){
        super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Focus Lock UnSucessfull!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    private void process(CaptureResult result){
        Log.i(TAG,"mSTATE_PICTURE_CAPTURED"+mState);
        switch (mState){


            case STATE_PREVIEW:

                break;
            case STATE_WAIT_AF_LOCK:
                Log.i(TAG,"process_ wait_AF_LOCK");

                Integer afState=result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                if(afState==CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED  || afState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED){

                    Log.i(TAG,"Lock Sucessfull!");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Lock Sucessfull!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    mState=STATE_PICTURE_CAPTURED;
                    captureStillImage();
                }
                Log.i(TAG,"Out of process_WAIT_AF_LOCK");
                break;
            case STATE_PICTURE_CAPTURED:

                break;
        }
    }
};
private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallback
        = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        Log.i(TAG,"CameraDeviceStateCallback+ onOpened");
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cam Opened!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        createCameraPreviewSession();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClosed(CameraDevice dev){
        mCameraDevice=null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        Log.i(TAG,"CameraDeviceStateCallback+ onDisconnected");
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
        Log.i(TAG, "Error Number:" + error + "While opening camera!!!");
    }
};

private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTexture = new
        TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                Log.i(TAG, "SurfaceTexture Available");
                setupCamera(width, height); 
                Log.i(TAG, "in onSurfaceTextureAvailable ");
                transformImage(width, height);
                Log.i(TAG, "in onSurfaceTextureAvailable ");
                openCamera();
                Log.i(TAG, "in onSurfaceTextureAvailable ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                Log.i(TAG, "in onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                Log.i(TAG, "in onSurfaceTextureTextureUpdated");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                Log.i(TAG, "SurfaceTexture Destroyed");
                return false;
            }
        };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    createImageFolder();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mRecycleView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.galleryRecyclerView);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        RecyclerView.Adapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(mImageFolder);
        Log.i(TAG, "RecyclerViewSetup!");
        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        Log.i(TAG, "TextureViewSetup!");
        mCaptureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.captureButton);
        mCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    else{
        if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST);

        }

    }

    Log.i(TAG,"onCreate Completed");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    openBackgroundThread();
    if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
        setupCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        transformImage(mTextureView.getWidth(),mTextureView.getHeight());
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                openCamera();
            }
        else {
            if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "App needs to be able to save Images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
        }

    } else {
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTexture);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    closeCamera();
    closeBackgroundThread();
    super.onPause();
}

public void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
    Log.i(TAG,"setupcam");
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            if (cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }
            StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);


            Size largestImageSize = Collections.max(
                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                    new Comparator<Size>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Size size, Size t1) {
                            return Long.signum(size.getWidth()*size.getHeight()- t1.getWidth()*t1.getHeight());
                        }
                    }
            );
            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largestImageSize.getWidth(),largestImageSize.getHeight(),ImageFormat.JPEG,1);

            mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener,mBackgroundHandler);

            mPreviewSize = getPrefferedPreviewSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), width, height);
            mCameraId = cameraId;
            Log.i(TAG,"Setup Camera Ends!!");
            return;
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private Size getPrefferedPreviewSize(Size[] mapSizes, int width, int height) {
    List<Size> collectorSizes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Size size : mapSizes) {
        if (width > height) {
            if (size.getWidth() > width && size.getHeight() > height) {
                collectorSizes.add(size);
            } else {
                if (size.getWidth() > height && size.getHeight() > width) {
                    collectorSizes.add(size);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    if (collectorSizes.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(collectorSizes, new Comparator<Size>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
                return Long.signum(lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() - rhs.getHeight() * rhs.getWidth());
            }
        });
    }
    return mapSizes[0];
}

public void openCamera() {
    Log.i(TAG,"In OpenCamera");
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        Log.i(TAG,"CamaeraManager.OpenCamera");
        cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        Log.i(TAG,"CamaeraManager.OpenCameraEnds");
    }
    catch(SecurityException s){
        s.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(CameraAccessException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG,"OpenCamera Ends");
}
public void closeCamera(){


    if(mImageReader!=null){
        mImageReader.close();
        mImageReader=null;
    }
    if(mCameraCaptureSession!=null) {
        mCameraCaptureSession.close();
        mCameraCaptureSession = null;
    }
    if(mCameraDevice!=null){
        mCameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
}
public void createCameraPreviewSession(){
    try{
        Log.i(TAG,"CREATE_PREVIEW_CAMERA_SESSION");
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture=mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(),mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder=mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
Arrays.asList(previewSurface,mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session){
                        Log.i(TAG,"mCameraDevice.careateCaptireSession onConfigured");
                        if(null == mCameraDevice){
                            return;
                        }
                        try{

                            mPreviewCaptureRequest=mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCameraCaptureSession = session;
                            mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewCaptureRequest,mSessionCaptureCallback,mBackgroundHandler);
                        }
                        catch(CameraAccessException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG,"mCameraDevice.careateCaptireSession onConfigured setRepeatingRequests");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session){
                        Log.i(TAG,"mCameraDevice.careateCaptireSession onConfigurationFailed");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CreateCameraSession FAILED!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                ,null);
    }catch(CameraAccessException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void clickPic(){
    Log.i(TAG,"in ClickPic");


    lockFocus();
    Log.i(TAG,"exiting ClickPic");
}

private void lockFocus(){
    try {
        Log.i(TAG,"lockFocus");

        mState = STATE_WAIT_AF_LOCK;

        mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);

        mCameraCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), mSessionCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    }catch(CameraAccessException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG,"exiting lockFocus");
}
private void unlockFocus(){
    try {
        Log.i(TAG,"unlockFocus");

        mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        mCameraCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),mSessionCaptureCallback,mBackgroundHandler);
        mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
        mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), mSessionCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    }catch(CameraAccessException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i(TAG,"exiting lockFocus");
}
private void openBackgroundThread(){
    mBackgroundThread=new HandlerThread("Camera Background Thread");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper()) {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Inside Background Handler");
        }
    };
}
private void closeBackgroundThread(){
    Log.i(TAG,"closing Background Thread!");
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try{
        mBackgroundThread.join();
        mBackgroundThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void captureStillImage(){

    try {
        Log.i(TAG,"captureStillImage");

        mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);

        mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));



        CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback =
                new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result){

                Log.i(TAG,"captureStillImage+ onCaptureCompleted"+mImageFileName);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Captured!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                unlockFocus();
            }
            public void onCaptureStarted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
                        super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
                        Log.i(TAG,"captureStillImage+ onCapturestarted");
                        try {
                            mImageFile=createImageFileName();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }
        };
        CameraCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
        mCameraCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),captureCallback,null);
    }catch(CameraAccessException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG,"captureStillImage Ends!");
}
private void transformImage(int width,int height){
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

if(mPreviewSize==null||mTextureView==null) {
    return;
}
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
RectF textureRectF = new RectF(0,0,width,height);
RectF previewRectF = new RectF(0,0,mPreviewSize.getHeight(),mPreviewSize.getWidth());
float centerX = textureRectF.centerX();
float centerY = textureRectF.centerY();
if(rotation==Surface.ROTATION_90||rotation==Surface.ROTATION_270){
    previewRectF.offset(centerX - previewRectF.centerX(),centerY-previewRectF.centerY());
    matrix.setRectToRect(textureRectF,previewRectF,Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
    float scale = Math.max((float)width/mPreviewSize.getWidth(),
            (float)height/mPreviewSize.getHeight());
    matrix.postScale(scale,scale,centerX,centerY);
    matrix.postRotate(90*(rotation-2),centerX,centerY);
}

mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.captureButton:
            clickPic();
            break;
    }
}
private void checkPermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        try {
            createImageFileName();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "App needs to be able to save Images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT);
    }

}
private void createImageFolder() {
    Log.i(TAG,"createImageFolder");
    File imageFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    mImageFolder = new File(imageFile, "camera2Api");
    if(!mImageFolder.exists()) {
        mImageFolder.mkdirs();
    }
}

private File createImageFileName() throws IOException {
    Log.i(TAG,"createImageFileName");
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String prepend = "IMG_" + timestamp + "_";
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".jpg", mImageFolder);
    mImageFileName = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.i(TAG,"Image FILE NAME="+mImageFileName);
    return imageFile;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Application will not run without camera services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Permission successfully granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST){
        if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Permission successfully granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
private void swapImageAdapter(){
    Log.i(TAG,"swapImageAdapter"+mImageFolder.toString()+"mGalleryFolder from MainActivity!!");
        RecyclerView.Adapter newImageAdapter=new ImageAdapter(mImageFolder);
        mRecycleView.swapAdapter(newImageAdapter,false);
}
private File[] sortFilesToLatest(File fileImagesDir) {
    File[] files = fileImagesDir.listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File lhs, File rhs) {
            return Long.valueOf(rhs.lastModified()).compareTo(lhs.lastModified());
        }
    });
    return files;
    }
    }
```

And this is the ImageAdapter class used to inflate the ImageViews in the RecyclerView:-

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private static final String TAG="ImageAdapter";
        private File imagesFile;

    public ImageAdapter(File folderFile) {
        Log.i(TAG,folderFile.toString()+"printing Folder File FROM IMAGE_ADAPTER!!!!");
        imagesFile = folderFile;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreateViewHolder");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_image, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onBindViewHolder");
        BitmapFactory.Options mBitOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        mBitOptions.inScaled=true;
        mBitOptions.inSampleSize=2;

        int size = imagesFile.listFiles().length;
        Log.i(TAG,imagesFile.toString()+" its SIZE="+size+" position="+position);
        Log.i(TAG,"CONSIDERING FILE:"+imagesFile.listFiles()[position].getPath());

        File imageFile = imagesFile.listFiles()[position];
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),mBitOptions);
        holder.getImageView().setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.i(TAG,"getItemCount");
        return imagesFile.listFiles().length;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageGalleryView);
        }

        public ImageView getImageView() {
            return imageView;
        }
        }
    }
```

```
Activity_main.xml



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/galleryRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/captureButton"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/captureButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/captureButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="@string/CaptureButtonString" />

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_image.xml contains an ImageView in a RelativeLayout. I could not provide code for it due to character restrictions.
Please advise what am I doing wrong?